# solana-test-validator error Illegal instruction: 4 after install solana 1.14.10

Tags: solana-test-validator, instruction

I am trying to update solana to 1.14.10, but after install it, solana-test-validator is not working. Here is error.

```
Notice! No wallet available. solana airdrop localnet SOL after creating one

Ledger location: test-ledger
Log: test-ledger/validator.log
⠚ Initializing...
Illegal instruction: 4
```

My mac is M1-chip
Please help me to solve this

Comment: Have you tried installing from source? https://github.com/solana-labs/solana
That usually fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Start by removing cache:

```
rm -rf .cache/solana
```

Reinstall Rust, and build Solana cli tools from source:

https://medium.com/coinmonks/solana-from-source-527cec3730b1

If still doesn't work try

```
brew install gnu-tar
```